TCP/IP for Oculus Quest 2
I am trying to send triggers for moving a sphere; from a computer in the following script, but I do not see any sphere in Oculus when I build and run, what can I do? (This works well for Unity ):
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class SphereThrower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject leftSpherePrefab;
    public GameObject rightSpherePrefab;
    public Transform leftWall;
    public Transform rightWall;

    private GameObject currentBall;
    private bool isLeftSphere;

    private Vector3 leftSphereInitialPosition;
    private Vector3 rightSphereInitialPosition;

    private TcpListener server5680;
    private TcpListener server5681;
    private int port5680 = 5680;
    private int port5681 = 5681;

    private ConcurrentQueue<(string message, int port)> messageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<(string message, int port)>();

    void Start()
    {
        if (leftSpherePrefab != null && rightSpherePrefab != null)
        {
            leftSphereInitialPosition = leftSpherePrefab.transform.position;
            rightSphereInitialPosition = rightSpherePrefab.transform.position;

            leftSpherePrefab.SetActive(false);
            rightSpherePrefab.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Left or right sphere prefab is not assigned!");
        }

        // Start TCP servers
        server5680 = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port5680);
        server5681 = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port5681);
        server5680.Start();
        server5681.Start();

        // Begin accepting clients asynchronously
        Task.Run(() => AcceptClients(server5680, port5680));
        Task.Run(() => AcceptClients(server5681, port5681));

        // Initialize VR settings
        InitializeVRSettings();
    }

    async Task AcceptClients(TcpListener server, int port)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

            // Handle client messages
            Task.Run(() => HandleClient(client, port));
        }
    }

    void HandleClient(TcpClient client, int port)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while (true)
        {
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break; // Client disconnected
            }
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead).TrimEnd('\0');

            // Enqueue message for processing on the main thread
            messageQueue.Enqueue((message, port));
        }

        client.Close();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Process messages from the queue on the main thread
        while (messageQueue.TryDequeue(out var messageInfo))
        {
            // Debug log to check if the message is received correctly
            Debug.Log("Processing message: " + messageInfo.message + " from port: " + messageInfo.port);

            // Call HandleTrigger method
            HandleTrigger(messageInfo.message, messageInfo.port);
        }
    }

    public void HandleTrigger(string trigger, int port)
    {
        if (port == port5680)
        {
            switch (trigger)
            {
                case "5":
                    Debug.Log("Trigger 1: Instantiating left sphere.");
                    InstantiateSphere(leftSpherePrefab, leftSphereInitialPosition);
                    isLeftSphere = true;
                    break;
                case "6":
                    Debug.Log("Trigger 2: Instantiating right sphere.");
                    InstantiateSphere(rightSpherePrefab, rightSphereInitialPosition);
                    isLeftSphere = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.Log("Invalid trigger received for port 5680: " + trigger);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (port == port5681)
        {
            switch (trigger)
            {
                case "7":
                    Debug.Log("Trigger 3: Throwing current ball to left wall.");
                    if (currentBall != null)
                    {
                        MoveBallToWall(currentBall, leftWall.position);
                    }
                    break;
                case "8":
                    Debug.Log("Trigger 4: Throwing current ball to right wall.");
                    if (currentBall != null)
                    {
                        MoveBallToWall(currentBall, rightWall.position);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Debug.Log("Invalid trigger received for port 5681: " + trigger);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    void InstantiateSphere(GameObject spherePrefab, Vector3 initialPosition)
    {
        if (spherePrefab == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Sphere prefab is null!");
            return;
        }

        if (currentBall != null)
        {
            Destroy(currentBall);
        }

        currentBall = Instantiate(spherePrefab, initialPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        currentBall.SetActive(true);
    }

    void MoveBallToWall(GameObject ball, Vector3 wallPosition)
    {
        if (ball == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No ball to move!");
            return;
        }

        Vector3 direction = wallPosition - ball.transform.position;
        direction.Normalize();

        Rigidbody rb = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.up * 5f; // Adjust the upward force as needed
            rb.useGravity = true; // Enable gravity to ensure the ball falls back down after hitting the wall
            rb.velocity += direction * 5f; // Set velocity to move the ball towards the wall
            Destroy(ball, 6.5f); // Destroy the ball after 6 seconds
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Rigidbody component missing on the sphere!");
        }
    }

    void InitializeVRSettings()
    {
        // Placeholder for any VR-specific initialization
        // Ensure that VR settings are correctly set up for the project
        if (!XRSettings.enabled)
        {
            XRSettings.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}

To run thsi in Quest 2; is there something else needed in the code or is is port of Quest2? I tried intergrating a camera rig; I see surrounding but not these spheres that are sent from another laptop as TCP triggers

Please edit your question and add a tag for the programming language you're using (c# ?).  Also, please add more debugging details.  When you drop a break point and step through your code, which line doesn't return the value you expect?  Then edit your code dump down to a Minimal, Reproduceable Example.
